# Excel VBA how to define minus decimal number

Tags: excel, decimal, vba

Well, how can define minus decimal numbers in excel vba, for example -0,5

```
Dim my_number as ?
my_number= Selection.Offset(0, 1).Value '-0,5
Label1.Caption = my_number
```

Comment: In my opinion this shows complete lack of effort on your part. For any language you can **easily** find a list of variable types from a simple Google search. Even if it still wasn't obvious to you, you could have tried a few and would've easily found what you needed

Comment: @CallumDA well at first u look right, but I asked this for double is 8 bytes and just for "-0.5" I am not prefer to lose 8 bytes

Comment: If you're after saving memory size you can also use the `Single` data type, which is 4 bytes. But use preferably `Double` unless you really have memory issues, i.e. a very large array of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minus is irrelevant, what matters is the decimal precision. A double would meet all potential needs in this situation (For context both long and integer can only handle whole integers)

```
Dim my_number as double
```

Answer (score 2):

For decimals you want to define them as [Doubles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99xtshc.aspx) regardless of whether they are negative or positive:

```
Dim my_number as Double
```

Extract from the Microsoft website (link provided):

> Holds signed IEEE 64-bit (8-byte) double-precision floating-point numbers that range in value from -1.79769313486231570E+308 through -4.94065645841246544E-324 for negative values and from 4.94065645841246544E-324 through 1.79769313486231570E+308 for positive values.